# How to identify 100% eapol packet?

Tags: ieee-802.11

How can i 100% identify a eapol protocol packet? I saw a key descriptor type "EAPOL RSN Key" and many more. But how can i say 100% "okay this is eapol"? Is there one or two bytes in the packet to make that clear?

Here is an example from the wireshark website (protocol EAPOL, Message 4 of 4):

```
0000   00 00 18 00 8e 58 00 00 10 6c 6c 09 c0 00 64 00
0010   00 38 00 00 ef 45 6f 70 08 01 2c 00 00 0c 41 82
0020   b2 55 00 0d 93 82 36 3a 00 0c 41 82 b2 55 a0 01
0030   aa aa 03 00 00 00 88 8e 02 03 00 5f 02 03 0a 00
0040   10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0050   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0060   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0070   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0080   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 bb a3 bd fb cf de
0090   2b c5 37 50 9d 71 f2 ec d1 00 00 ef 45 6f 70
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EAPoL is used within 802.1X, so you'll be looking for an Ethertype of 0x888E.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you also know, where the info is stored? As an example: 'Message 2 of 4' -> http://imgur.com/a/aehKo

Comment: The Ethertype starts at offset 12 / 0x0C in the frame (or 16 / 0x10 with 802.1Q tag). In your example above you can spot it at 0x36.

Comment: Yes, i saw that. I can see the eapol with 0x888E. But now i want to know, how i can see which message it is. Is it message 1 of 4 or 4 of 4?

Comment: You won't find a sequence number in the data. EAP is a lock-step protocol where you've got to look at the entire dialogue chain. You can find details in [RFC3748](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3748) and IEEE 802.1X.

Comment: more specifically, the `aa aa 03` at offset `0030` is an LLC header indicating that the five following octets `00 00 00 88 8e` are a SNAP header, where that has an OUI value of `00 00 00` and EtherType value `88 8e`.  The EAPoL data follows immediately thereafter.   Annoyingly, IEEE 802.11 is a big mish-mash of big-endian and little-endian encodings :(